# Picasso keeping the old image until new image loaded

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-imageview, picasso

I have a fragment that i'm calling again and again it has Picasso in it to load images from url when I pop back same fragment with different url to load image from, the previous image shown until new image loaded, how can i solve this problem, here is my code:

```
Picasso.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE)
                .into(ivParallex, new com.squareup.picasso.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {                         
                     getProductDetail(productId);
                    } else {


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Add placeholder maybe issue will solve.

Comment: let me check...

Comment: @blackHawk `.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)`

Comment: checking .......

Comment: If above ans not working then try
.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)

Comment: Add `.placeHolder` may solve your problem.

Comment: It already has place holder and memory policy but didnt work, actually fragment is calling again and again and there is only instance of picasso

Comment: you can do one thing that whenever you are opening your fragment manually set background image to your ivParallex view

Comment: Try to invalidate the previous URL before the fragment shows again: picasso.with(yourContext).invalidate(previousURL) or picasso.invalidate(previousURL)